# Does a Service in Android stop when the calling Activity/Fragment changes orientation?

Tags: android, android-service

I am looking at the doc but it doesn't really explain this anywhere. I did find this:

```
The service will at this point continue running until Context.stopService() 
or stopSelf() is called.
```

What this tells me is the Service will continue running, but that is assuming when orientation change occurs that the Activity/Fragment does not automatically stop services it has started. I also found this:

```
Using startService() overrides the default service lifetime that is managed by
bindService(Intent, ServiceConnection, int): it requires the service to remain 
running until stopService(Intent) is called, regardless of whether any 
clients are connected to it.
```

Can I assume that the Service will actually not stop until I explicitly call `stopService`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for the title, answer is no.

A service doesn't stops when the calling activity/fragment changes orientation. It continues running unless or untill it is stopped explicitly

for the description, the answer is yes.

you definitely need to call either of the functions `stopService()` or `stopSelf()` to stop the service.

Comment: Haha, I figure you read my comment on the other answer. Thanks! :) very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

Yes.You have to stop it using stopService() method or you can use stopSelf() to stop when the the service is no longer needed.it will automatically stop the service.

Comment: Yes it will NOT stop the service? Lol, sorry, I worded the question weird so now I am not sure if your'e saying yes to the title or the question on the last line.

Comment: i have said yes to this line "Can I assume that the Service will actually not stop until I explicitly call stopService?"